# Tense slip: "have done sth when I realized"?

Tags: past-tense, present-perfect

> Most of the confidences were unsought —frequently I **have** feigned sleep, preoccupation, or a hostile levity when I **realized** by some unmistakable sign that an intimate revelation was quivering on the horizon.

<sup>(*The Great Gatsby*, by F. Scott Fitzgerald, emphasis added)</sup>

I think it's better to write "I feigned sleep.. when I realized..."

Thanks for the example in the first answer,
I feel ok about "when I have eaten apples I have gotten very sick"
but how about "when I ate apples I have gotten very sick"? what's the difference between this two?

A new question: To show that I still feign sleep when I realize an intimate revelation.
Isn't it better to say "frequently I have feigned sleep, preoccupation, or a hostile levity when I **have realized** by some unmistakable sign that an intimate revelation was quivering on the horizon."

Answer (score 1):

No, it's better the way that it is, although both are possible.  You might want to refer to [the differences between the simple past (*feigned*) vs. the present perfect (*have feigned*)](https://learningenglish.voanews.com/a/everyday-grammar-simple-past-and-present-perfect/2752310.html).

**I feigned sleep** would suggest that the action was completely in the past.

**I have feigned sleep** suggests a connection to the present, and that maybe the action or sequence of actions is not complete yet.

For example, in

> When I **ate** apples...

the use of the simple past **ate** suggests that we are talking about something that only happened in the past.  You might use that like

> When I ate apples, I would get very sick.  But now I am on medicine so that I don't get sick any more.

But

> When I **have eaten** apples...

suggests a connection to the present (remember that the *present* perfect is actually a *present* tense!)  You might use that like

> Would I like an apple?  No, when I have eaten apples I have gotten very sick, so I don't think I want to eat one now.

Comment: I've updated the question.It would be wrong to write "when I was a child, I have eaten a lot of sweets", isn't it? It's about the difference of "feign" and "feigned" in this particular context.