# Is it wrong to say "when I was a child, I have eaten a lot of sweets"?

Tags: present-perfect, past-simple

I think we need to say "**when I was** a child, I **ate** a lot of sweets"

Similarly, is it wrong to say "frequently I **have feigned** sleep, preoccupation, or a hostile levity **when I realized** by some unmistakable sign that an intimate revelation was quivering on the horizon"? (The Great Gatsby, by F. Scott Fitzgerald, emphasis added)

I think we need to say "frequently I **feigned** sleep, preoccupation, or a hostile levity **when I realized** by some unmistakable sign that an intimate revelation was quivering on the horizon"

Thanks for the example--- "I have recently seen a lot of bad behavior by teenagers when I went to the beach."

Present perfect means the past action still happening now, so "have seen" means both "saw" and "see". The narrator still sees a lot of bad behavior by teenagers now, that's for sure, but does the narrator still sees it when he or she goes to the beach? Or somewhere else?

I understand  "Recently I saw a lot of bad behavior by teenagers when I went to the beach."

But I am disconcerted about "I see a lot of bad behavior by teenagers when I went to the beach."

Comment: Isn't this the same question you asked two days ago?  https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/177603/tense-slip-have-done-sth-when-i-realized

Comment: @stangdon New different answers lead to new different questions. I've updated my questions, please come back to see both updates. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

"Frequently I have feigned sleep, preoccupation, or a hostile levity [in the past continuing on in the present] when I realized by some unmistakable sign that an intimate revelation was quivering on the horizon" [F. Scott Fitzgerald]

My example: The professors **have often given accurate descriptions** of historical events [this merely signals a past which continues to be true at the time of speaking] **when they felt** they needed to so.

It is not incorrect to have the present perfect in one clause that refers to something that is in the past and continues to be true in the present and then qualify it with past situations using the simple past in when clauses.

- I have recently seen a lot of bad behavior by teenagers when I went to the beach.

The when clause suggests there were multiple instances of this event.